# Snippets in Avalon Edit

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

In avalon edit there is a snippet class **SnippetReplaceableTextElement** and I can't understand how to use it correctly, I wrote something like that and it doesn't work:

```
        SnippetReplaceableTextElement snip = new SnippetReplaceableTextElement();
        snip.Text = "Console.WriteLine();";
        InsertionContext context = new InsertionContext(textEditor.TextArea, 0);
        snip.Insert(context);
```

The insertion itself occurs, but the selection doesn't work. How to make the snippet work like in visual studio? Class source: https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/blob/28b887f78c821c7fede1d4fc461bde64f5f21bd1/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Snippets/SnippetReplaceableTextElement.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something like this: https://github.com/typicalHuman/typicalIDE/tree/master/CodeBox/Completions/CSCompletion/Snippets
It isn't ideal, but suitable for the base.

Answer (score 0):

its an old post, but: on the web there are no results how to use snippets in AvalonEdit.
After some research i found a simple solution:
The example is a simple reimplementation of VStudio "prop" snippet.

```
        Snippet snip = new Snippet();
        snip.Elements.Add(new SnippetTextElement()            { Text = "public " });
        snip.Elements.Add(new SnippetReplaceableTextElement() { Text = "int" });
        snip.Elements.Add(new SnippetTextElement()            { Text = " " });
        snip.Elements.Add(new SnippetReplaceableTextElement() { Text = "MyProperty" });
        snip.Elements.Add(new SnippetTextElement()            { Text = " { get; set; }" });
        snip.Insert(AvalonTextEditor.TextArea);
```

Now you get a text insertion with two SnippetReplaceableText elements. You can navigate to the next SnippetReplaceableTextElement with TAB and accept with ENTER.

Here the example result:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

It is very basic but i hope it helps.